# How to access MySql database with WordPress in local machine ?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am unable to access database while creating a WordPress powered website in my local machine.

Is any plug-in available to access database from dashboard?

Comment: wordpress is php/mysql driven. If you are getting to the dashboard then everything is functioning as expected. If you are wanting to see the tables of wordpress then you will need to use and external db app like  phpmyadmin

Comment: I don't think you can access database form WordPress dashboard. If you using xampp for installing WordPress on local machine, go to  XAMPP control panel, you should see a admin link to mysql. Simply click on it.